# IntelliJ configure own SBT folder structure

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, build, sbt, directory-structure

I want to use my very own folder structure for a SBT-project in intellij.

So I configure it in the project structure settings menu.

I want the folders to be like this:

```
src
- main
- test
res
```

I do **not** want any java, scala or whatever folders. Now, this kind of works, until I add another dependency in my build.sbt. As soon as I do that, everything resets and I have to do reset all the settings manually. I'm kind of desperate now. I just want **my** folder structure to work.

Any ideas why this always resets?

Comment: You are recommended to follow the best practices. Why do you need to define your own project structure?

Comment: @LuongBaLinh: Why would I want a java or scala_2.11 folder if all classes I ever wrote were in the scala folder? I've developed in c++ and a lot of other languages and I do not want to be restrained. I never break best practices, but this time they do not make any sense to me and as I'm the only one working on this project I do not see any reason why I should subdue to them?! I want the same setup as I would have in a c++ environment. one src folder with all the packages in it, one build-folder with two subfolders for release and development and a resource folder outside the src folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is decided settings in your sbt build, when you change the build.sbt file IntelliJ needs to rebuild its own internal model of the project and reloads that from SBT which resets changes you have done in IntelliJ.

I'm not sure how good it will work in IntelliJ with custom paths but you should be changing scalaSource (and possibly javaSource) in your build.sbt rather than through the IntelliJ menus.

You can read more about the sbt source configuration keys here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Classpaths.html